# Leaflet: open popup at cursor position instead of LineString center

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a leaflet map with a `LineString`.

```
// a GeoJSON LineString
var geojson = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[-101.123, 40.2500], [-101.123, 40.2503]]
  }
};

// create map and add json
var map = L.map('map');
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds())

// add popup for the line
geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  var popup = L.popup();
  popup.setContent('text');

  layer.bindPopup(popup);
  layer.on('click mouseover', function () {
    layer.openPopup();
  });
});
```

When I over it, a popup opens at the LineString center.

How can I make it open over at the cursor position?

Here is a simple working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wuu8Lv2t/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't let the layer open the popup, instead use `openOn(map)` setting the position with the coordinates from the event `e.latlng`

```
// add popup for the line
geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  var popup = L.popup();
  popup.setContent('text');
  layer.bindPopup(popup);

  layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
    var popup = e.target.getPopup();
    popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).openOn(map);
  });

  layer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
     e.target.closePopup();
  });

  layer.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    e.target.closePopup();
    var popup = e.target.getPopup();
    popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).openOn(map);
  });
});
```

Note that in your question there is a mistake: you can't use the variable `layer` in the event hander, you have to use `e.target` (see [doc](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#evented)).

Comment: Note that you could have to throttle the mouseout/ousemove event if you want the popup to be interactive.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [an answer](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5235#issuecomment-271094105) from [Per Liedman](https://github.com/perliedman), a Leaflet maintainer:

> You can achieve this by creating a new popup and adding at the desired location, instead of binding it. Since a bound popup can be opened by other means than a mouse click, it can't know where to open.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
// a GeoJSON LineString
var geojson = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[-101.123, 40.2500], [-101.123, 40.2503]]
  }
};

// create map and add json
var map = L.map('map');
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds())

// add popup for the line
geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {

  layer.on('click mouseover', function (e) {
    var popup = L.popup()
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent('text')
        .openOn(map);
  });
});
```

See here for a modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/uwdnvfy6/

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer (by @YaFred) is pretty good, what's key is the update function `layer.on('mousemove'...` . However, as written, closing and opening the popup every time your mouse moves, makes it flicker. Instead, in `layer.('mousemove...` you only need the line that updates the location:

```
// add popup for the layer
geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  var popup = L.popup();
  popup.setContent('text');
  layer.bindPopup(popup);

  layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
    var popup = e.target.getPopup();
    popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).openOn(map);
  });

  layer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
     e.target.closePopup();
  });

  // update popup location
  layer.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).openOn(map);
  });
});
```